# post request with 3 parameters in python

Tags: python, http, post, python-requests

I am going to write a code to send post requests to a website and getting results. 
The post request have 3 parameters as you can see from this figure:(in the section of form data) d,n, q
[image]

I have tried the following code but always getting error.

```
import requests
url = 'http://www.kloth.net/services/nslookup.php'
payload = {'d':'google.com','n':'localhost', 'd':'SOA'}

session = requests.Session()
 session.post(url',headers=headers,data=payload)
```

can you help me how to fix this issue!

Comment: Why does your dictionary look like {'d':value,'n':value,'d':value}, so d,n,d when your Form Data seems to require d,n,q.  ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import requests    

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36',
           'Host:www.kloth.net',
           'Origin':'http://www.kloth.net',
           'Proxy-Connection':'keep-alive',
           'Referer':'http://www.kloth.net/services/nslookup.php}
payload = {'d': 'google.com',
           'n': 'localhost',
           'q': 'SOA}
session = requests.Session()
return =  session.post('http://www.kloth.net/services/nslookup.php', data = payload, headers = headers)
print str(return.content)
```

You didn't specified your headers,